# LSTM / Pretrained word embedding - Positive/Negative review prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have one Thousand review sentences (or paragraphs) with associated Positive or Negative labels (Same one Thousand), so i am trying to use glove word embedding (Pretrained word representation), so below is the architecture have been decided (Many to One).

By considering below image as single review prediction,

I am trying to fixing each sentence up to 1000 words (time sequence) (Either by removing extra words or Padding by zero vectors) [each word would be transformed into 300D array]

But i don't know how to materialize this architecture in Keras or Tensorflow

Getting lot of confusions about the shapes of each cells, can any one explain the shapes accordingly (Each cell in LSTM) by considering 1 layer LSTM with 1000 word sequence (And each word is gonna have 300D vector/array).

[image]

Architeture Picture[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to decide few hyperparameters for model .

So if your sentence length is fixed then use 1000 in placeholder otherwise use 'None' :

```
sentence = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,1000],dtype=tf.int32,name='sentences')

then define labels :

labels = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,],dtype=tf.int32,name='labels')
```

So if your sentence batch is 10 and length is 1000:

> sentence = [10x1000]

Now you can either use Embedding from scratch or you can use pre-trained Embedding. For using pre-trained embedding you use can define variable like this:

```
Word_embedding = tf.get_variable(name="Word_embedding", 
                                 shape=[24,100], 
                                 initializer=tf.constant_initializer(np.array(load_embedding_matrix)), 
                                 trainable=False
                                )


embedding_loopup= tf.nn.embedding_lookup(Word_embedding,sentences)
```

> After embedding lookup your sentence will become [10x1000x300]

Here is [full detailed tutorial](https://github.com/monk1337/word_embedding-in-tensorflow/blob/master/Use%20Pre-trained%20word_embedding%20in%20Tensorflow.ipynb) on Embedding in Tensorflow .

After you have to feed this to LSTM model , But since you are using padding so you have to provide sequence_length to LSTM which is actual length of sentence.

```
sequence_leng = tf.count_nonzero(sentence,axis=-1)
```

Now at LSTM part you have to define Num_units of LSTM which are nodes in LSTM unit , simple dynamic rnn with lstm example is:

```
with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    cell= tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_units=100)
    rnn_output = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell,embedding_loopup,sequence_leng,dtype=tf.float32)
```

Now your num_units are 100 for example then :

> each time_step output shape will be 10x 100 and final output of rnn
>   which contains all time step shape will be 10x1000x100

for projection you have to take last timestep output :

```
transpose the output ==> 10x1000x100 to 1000x10x100 now take last timestep 10x100
```

> After projection is [10x100] x [hidden_unit x no_of categories]
>   suppose your categories are 2 labels
>
> [10x100] x [100x 2] then final output will be 10x2

from there take the argmax probability index which will be your prediction.

Now take last output of rnn and project with linear projection without any activation function.

Here is [sentiment tutorial](https://github.com/monk1337/LSTM_sentiment_analysis) with bi-directional rnn.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation to newbie. I have couple of doubts. 1. Word Embedding shape that you have mentioned [24,100] (My case it should be #unique vocabulary count X 300 (Pretrained Glove)) Doubt 2: What do you mean by batchsize 10? Is it mean to say 10 training example? Doubt 3: num_units = 100, what and how 100 came into the picture, is it some thing arbitrary value- I am not able to associate the relevance with the above architecure picture.. Its my bad to understand equivalence between theory/math vs Tensorflow/Theano/Keras

Comment: 1) yes , vocab size is 24 there , in your case [ vocab_size x embedding_dim ]
2) batchsize 10 means 10 example at a time for training.
3) num_units are neurons (nodes) in lstm_cell. those are arbitrary , usually values are 50,100,150,200,250 ,300 etc try with different values and find best one.

Comment: Why you didn't use LSTMStateTuple (h-output)? but you have used hidden state (c - hidden state). //// concat_output = tf.concat([last_state[0].c,last_state[1].c],axis=-1) ////